# Finding orphaned SpecFlow steps

Tags: cucumber, specflow

SpecFlow has the ability to generate a StepDefinitionReport.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to list steps for which there is code, but the step is not actually used in any *.feature file.  SpecFlow source code doesn't look like it's actually parsing the C# code, only the *.feature files, so it will never report a step with 0 uses.

Is there any other tool out there that will report orphaned steps?  We have several hundred steps and multiple feature files that I'd rather not have to crawl them manually to find orphans.

Comment: not a great solution, but we use NCrunch which shows uncovered code with white dots and produces a code coverage report, both of which make it simple to see the methods that are not covered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the StepDefinitionReport with a trivial example in 5 minutes and it *does* report the orphaned steps. There must be another problem in your case. Also in the source code you can find the place where it collects the bindings: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Reporting/StepDefinitionReport/StepDefinitionReportGenerator.cs#L38

[image]